# Read More/Less button with text HTML dynamically triggered using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}
.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}
.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}
.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
<div class="read-more-wrap"><?php echo substr($row_RS_Product['Full_Description'], 0, 500); ?>
  <span class="read-more-target"><?php echo substr($row_RS_Product['Full_Description'], 500); ?></span></div>
<label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```

**What this code does is the following:**
It shows the first 500 characters until is reaches the first paragraph, it then displays the rest of the text as well with the full markup.

**If I remove the content as follows:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
<div class="read-more-wrap"><?php echo substr($row_RS_Product['Full_Description'], 0, 500); ?> <span class="read-more-target"></span></div>
<label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```

The content of the read-more-wrap is displayed correctly (the first 500 characters with correct markup). However there is obviously noting else to read more.

When changing the `<span class="read-more-target">` to `<div>` it works almost correctly, however the words just break up anyhow e.g. when becomes

```
wh
en
```

Comment: So... what is the question?

Comment: @Morpheus, sorry somebody edited the question out. I would like it to just work so for a start the words don't break up and just to make sure that after displaying the first 500 characters and the show more button is clicked the writing continuos as if it was one piece of text (including proper mark up)

Comment: I have taken your example, put on fiddle and don't see the behaviour you have explained -> https://jsfiddle.net/xrtxqu94/ Do you have any html within the text?

Comment: What happens is that the text that is retrieved contains e.g multiple<p>jsdfhgsjdhgf</p><p>jsdfhgsjdhgf</p>. This is where it doesn't work. If it would have been as shown in the Fiddle no paragraph mark up it would work

Comment: Are you allowed to remove html tags? If so, use `strip_tags` before you cut the text -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php